# Date giving wrong year on Device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have no idea what is going on. I am using XCode 8.2.1.

I have method that returns String of current date.

```
    static func getCurrentDate() -> String {

    let date = Date()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.YYYY"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    return dateString
}
```

Now everything look ok, and it is ok, when I run my application in Simulator. But, when I run app on my device I get weird results. This started happening few days ago and I have no idea what is going on.

The output in console is:

```
dateString  String  "29.12.2017"    
date    Date    2016-12-29 09:38:45 UTC
```

You can notice that dateString has year **2017** instead of **2016**.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: It is `yyyy` not `YYYY`, so change dateFormat to "dd.MM.yyyy"

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: I did not even notice the "YYYY" problem. It iis weird that it was working until lately. Anyway, problem solved.

Comment: Check that duplicate link answer it will give you more understanding.